# How to append text correctly to replace part of original text

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having an issue inserting text into a textbox. Virtually what I am trying to do is copy a piece of text from 'richTextBox1', process it and then insert the processed data in 'richTextbox2' (there is already text in 'richTextBox2' above. The processed text should come underneath.

The problem I have is that everytime I click on a button to process instead of replacing the text, it just adds in another block of text. I'm not sure how to replace it instead of add it.

For example my richTextbox2 looks like this at first:

> "Hello", my name is Bruce
>
> ---

I click on btnVowels, it looks like this:

> Hello, my name is Bruce
>
> ---
>
> "Hll", my nm s Brc

Above is fine, but then problem is that now if I click on btnAlpha, it displays this:

> Hello, my name is Bruce
>
> ---
>
> "Hll", my nm s Brc Hello my name is Bruce

I want it to go:

> "Hello", my name is Bruce
>
> ---
>
> Hello, my name is Bruce

Does anybody have any ideas?

```
/* already at start of richTextBox2 when clicking on a different button:

string nl = System.Environment.NewLine;
string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;
richTextBox2.Text = copyText;

richTextBox2.AppendText(lineBreak + "----------------------" + lineBreak);

*/


private void btnVowels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;
    string vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";
    copyText = new string(copyText.Where(c => !vowels.Contains(c)).ToArray());

    richTextBox2.AppendText(copyText);
}

private void btnAlpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;
    string nonAlpha = @"[^A-Za-z ]+";
    string addSpace = "";
    copyText = Regex.Replace(copyText, nonAlpha, addSpace);

    richTextBox2.AppendText(copyText);
}
```

UPDATE:

Still haven't got it to work, I have set up a string called divider which is the ----------- line and try to see if I can select that and then paste but no luck as it doesn't recognize copyText in the debugger after I click on button:

```
 private void btnVowels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


 int startingIndex = richTextBox2.Find(divider);
 string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;
 string vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";
 copyText = new string(copyText.Where(c => !vowels.Contains(c)).ToArray());
 richTextBox2.Select(startingIndex, divider.Length);

 richTextBox2.SelectedText = copyText;

    }
```

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Why don't you richTextBox2.Text = copyText; instead of AppendText?

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Windows Forms Application

Comment: I posted an answer for you

Comment: @RodrigoLópez Because it will replace the unprocessed text at the top. I still need the unprocessed text on the top of the text box, I then want the processed text to be displayed underneath.

Comment: How do you reach 1k rep without knowing to add the [tag:winforms] tag?

Comment: @JohnSaunders C# is really a new language I am learning.

Comment: He is referring to adding a winforms tag to your Stackoverflow question. This is specific to WinForms and not necessarily C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AppendText` will just append the text to the end, which isn't what you want. Instead, you must find the text you want to replace and select it. Once it is selected, you can overwrite it.

This is a full example. The Form sets its RichTextBox to say

> "Hello", my name is Bruce.

Then when the button is clicked, it replaces `"Hello"` with `Hi`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the starting index for the content we want to replace.
        int startingIndex = richTextBox1.Find("\"Hello\"");

        // Select the content to be replaced.
        richTextBox1.Select(startingIndex, "\"Hello\"".Length);

        // Replace the content.
        richTextBox1.SelectedText = "Hi";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "\"Hello\", my name is Bruce";
    }
}
```

#### Edit

This update shows you how to find the divider line, grab the index for the first char on the following line and then select the remainder of the text. Then we can replace it.

```
private void btnVowels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string copyText = this.RemoveVowelsFromString(richTextBox1.Text);  
    richTextBox2.AppendText(copyText);
}

private void btnAlpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;
    string nonAlpha = @"[^A-Za-z ]+";
    string addSpace = "";
    copyText = Regex.Replace(copyText, nonAlpha, addSpace);

    // Replace the content beneath the divider
    string divider = "------------";

    // Find the first char index of the divider line
    int dividerIndex = richTextBox2.Find(divider);

    // grab the line number that the divider is on
    int dividerLine = richTextBox2.GetLineFromCharIndex(dividerIndex);

    // get the first char on the line following the divider
    int startingIndex = richTextBox2.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(dividerLine+1);

    // Select everything starting after the divider to be replaced.
    richTextBox2.Select(startingIndex, richTextBox2.Text.Length - startingIndex);

    // Replace the content.
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = copyText;
}

private string RemoveVowelsFromString(string content)
{
    string vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";
    copyText = new string(copyText.Where(c => !vowels.Contains(c)).ToArray());

    return copyText;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just one little issue I can't figure out and then I will leave you alone, this line:   `richTextBox2.Select(startingIndex, richTextBox2.Length - startingIndex);` The Length has a wiggly line underneath as it can't fine that method, finds .TextLength but when I run programme, it faults to that line of code.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get for doing examples on my phone. You need to do `richTextBox.Text.Length - startingIndex`. I'll update my answer to match that.

Comment: I tried that as well previously but no give, keeps coming up with:      An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'start'.

Comment: -1 indicates it can not find the line you are looking. Take a look at the MSDN documentation on [GetFirstCharIndexFromLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getfirstcharindexfromline(v=vs.110).aspx), [GetLineFromCharIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex(v=vs.110).aspx), [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfcsf75k(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is there a way instead where I can create an empty object and place the change in there? So if I did                 `richTextBox2.AppendText("Help" + divider + block);` Is there a way I can set block as like an object globally and for each button clicked just replace the text within that block?

Comment: That is not the direction you want to go. My answer does what it needs to do, I've tested it and it works.

Comment: Ok then, take your advice, thank you very much and I will try to find that line. I'm assuming it's because my divider is set as `string divider = "------------------------" + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine;` that's maybe why there's an issue

Comment: You can do something like that if you want, I can put together an example later on (not at a computer). You would not want it to be glob nor do you want to use `appendText` to do it though.

Comment: Ok Jonathon, I will wait for your example as that even though I managed to sort out that error, it is still causing issues because of like you the append.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing append. My example shows you replacing `SelectedText`

Comment: Issue is it keeps displaying error with selectedText so that isn't really working. 'm going to mark your answer and call it a night. I will post another question but change my thinking of doing it so second textbox is blank, copy text from first testbox as well as adding additional content underneath. When clicking on another button, it will just replace the whole text. That's probably best way to sort it even though it means loading up the same text again with the new additional text below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you don't need to copy the original string

```
string nonAlpha = @"[^A-Za-z ]+";
string addSpace = "";
richTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, nonAlpha, addSpace);
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to replace all of the contents of the textbox. Rather he wants to replace the applicable contents within the textbox only.

Comment: What Jonathon said, only the applicable content (the content underneath). I cal it unprocessed content at top and processed content at bottom, only the processed text can be replaced, the unprocessed text doesn't get touched.

Comment: Why not just have two text boxes then?

Comment: The specification states that it must be unprocessed data, followed by --------------- then followed by processed data underneath. It all has to be in one place as well as saving it all to a text file later.